# A good design pattern for a Web API where models/enities are searchable by foreign keys

Tags: rest, web, api-design

I was hoping someone might have some ideas on how to create a RESTful web API where models/entities are searchable by a foreign key. I see a a lot of tutorials where the functionality consist of listing all records in the entire model or retrieving a single record from the model by a primary key, but not by an arbitrary/foreign key. It my be as simple as checking for extra conditions in the request but I thought I would get some advice all the same.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 10):

First of all, you are going to design a very poor API if you are thinking of "foreign keys" while you design said API. As an API designer, your business is *resources*, not *entities* or *keys*.

If you think in terms of resources then the answer is really pretty obvious. You either have an embedded resource (orders belonging to a customer) or you have a query.

Embedded resources are just like subdirectories. You use the path for that:

```
/api/customers/4/orders
```

And a query is, not surprisingly, a query string:

```
/api/orders?customerId=4
```

Or, some people feel that this is more RESTful:

```
/api/orders?customer=/api/customers/4
```

All of these are fine. It's partly a matter of preference and partly a matter of just how complex your relationships are.

But one thing is for sure, you're on the wrong track talking about things primary keys and foreign keys. Those are database terms and APIs have nothing to do with your database. It's not uncommon at all to have multiple representations of the same resource, for example:

```
/api/customers/123/
/api/customers/acme+inc/
/api/customers/123-acme+inc/
/api/customers/123/acme+inc/
/api/customers/me/ (say you are ACME Inc.)
```

The whole idea of a REST API is that these resources identifiers (URIs) are opaque. You don't know what the "primary key" is, and you *might* not be entirely sure what the "ID" is. So again, just repeating one more time for the record, don't use database terminology when you're reasoning about a Web API, it will lead you to the wrong design.

Comment: I think one thing thats also worth bringing up in your discussion is that depending upon your data relationship, it may make sense to even provide access in a REST api to both sides of a relationship to the embedded resource. This can further allow hiding those data tier concerns from an API user.

Comment: /api/customers/4/orders Makes sense. I am going to fix my API routes. What about getting all customers, like on a customer index page?